# IOS5 Is it possible to change the text of Double-high status bar?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios5

In IOS SDK, is it possible to change the heading of the Top red status bar(Double high status bar) as referred in the following [link.](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/TechnologyUsage/TechnologyUsage.html)

We are implementing a Voip app and we would like to make that more meaningful than just say "Recording"...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to do this. The double-height status bar is only used for VoIP and audio recording, as well as Personal Hotspot connections.

However, it you're interested in putting custom text in the status bar, then there are many great solutions (the one that I use is https://github.com/myell0w/MTStatusBarOverlay). And the best part is, it's not in violation if Apple's policies! Many apps, including the Gmail app, use this and have been on the App Store for a long time.